# mysql group by multiple

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I'm not sure if this is specifically a group by question, as I've tried grouping this by multiple columns. Basic problem is a table like this:

[image]

I would like to get the sum of the order total_price for different countries, but grouped by the order_id. So for France the sum of total_price should be 8000 as two of the rows are for the same order. My sql is clearly wrong as I am not getting this.

```
SELECT sum(total_price) as total_price_per_country
FROM cars
WHERE (country IN ('France'))
group by order_id, country;
```

Comment: order_id isn't unique. The first two rows have the same order_id

Answer (score 0):

Nope, `GROUP BY` won't quite get you that. If you `GROUP BY` country you get one row per country.

There's no way to do this without a second query, so it'd have to be something like this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(total_price) FROM cars AS c2 WHERE c2.country = cars.country) AS total_price_per_country
FROM cars
```

(An `INNER JOIN` to a second copy of the table would work too.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(total_price) from cars where country = 'France' group by order_id
```

Try above query

Comment: that just groups by orders from france. returns a table with 6000, 2000, and 3000

Comment: Yes, So that groups the record with order_id 1, 4 and 5 .
That is what you want , right ??

For order_id 1 you have two records with total_price 3000 each.
Thats 6000.
for order_id 4 its 2000 and for order_id 5 its 3000.

Comment: No, mentioned in the OP, i want 8000 to be returned. This is the sum of the total price for unique orders in France. The rows are a breakdown of various parts of the order. THe first two rows are the same order. The 3000 is a duplicate total amount

Comment: select max(order_id),sum(total_price) from (select order_id from cars where country = 'France') group by order_id

Comment: Try `select sum(part_price) from cars where country = 'France'`

Comment: @Priyanshu unfortunately that returns the same thing.

Comment: @Erik Peterson I see your logic, but I am not sure how dependable the part_price data is so total_price needs to be used

Comment: select distinct order_id,sum(total_price) from (select order_id from cars where country = 'France') group by order_id